# How many times does $37$ appear between $0$ to $1,000,000$?

Tags: combinatorics, recreational-mathematics

I was thinking about the problem 'How many times does the digit $7$ appear in all numbers $0$ to $1,000,000$?". This is easy enough so the obvious extension is how many times does some $2$-digit number appear? For example

> How many times does $37$ appear between $0$ to $1,000,000$?

For example:
$437,009$ contains one $37$, $373,737$ contains three $37$s. How many total $37$s appear if we write the numbers down?

My initial thoughts is that the answer ought to have something to do with the number of $7$s that appear from $0$ to $100,000$ as it looks like there's a bijection (where you simply get rid of the $3$ from the $37$ in the 6 digit number to give you a $5$ digit number) but this doesn't work for a few reasons.
I otherwise can't make progress. Perhaps it's a matter of considering cases; how many have one $37$ in them, how many have two $37$s in them, etc.

> How about for $77$ (where something like $777$ would count as two $77$s)?

Thank you.

Comment: Re: $777$ being two $77$s, isn't that up to you since this is a problem you were thinking about?  Given this post in its entirety I'd say yes since there is no restriction on reusing single digits as part of different groups.  Also, $37$, $23$, $77$... what?

Comment: Ah I think I worded that horribly. It was supposed to be "how many $77$s if we count $777$ as two $77$s?" opposed to "would $777$ count as two $77$s?" I'll edit now. No idea where 23 came from, I'll edit again. Sorry about that

Comment: I mean it isn't slightly clear what you are trying to say.

Comment: Ok I'll give an example in an edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How many have $37$ as the final two digits ie $xxxx37$? How many have $xxx37x$? - well there are $10^4$ possibilities for the $x$. Count all the examples - you end up counting $x37x37$ twice, and $373737$ three times, as you seem to want.

You can do exactly the same with $77$ because $xxx777$ gets counted twice, $xx7777$ three times etc.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yeah ok this isn't bad at all. I think when my initial ideas didn't work and I couldn't find a trick to do it quickly I convinced myself it was a hard question. It's just a case of counting. Thanks